# Reason for Playstore xamarin android app crashing?

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, maui

My live app is crashing. Below is the crash log. I am not able to find the reason from the log.
Can anyone one point out where could be the issue from logs please.

The main message exception I get is android.os.TransactionTooLargeException : data parcel size 542708 bytes.

The counts are scary high

After looking at other similar issues on internet I come to know it might be crashing when changing data between activities or when minimizing app but still not sure.

I need some suggestion where should I be looking into

full log is attached. I will also be keep looking into it thanks.

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 542708 bytes
      at android.app.ActivityClient.activityStopped(ActivityClient.java:92)
      at android.app.servertransaction.PendingTransactionActions$StopInfo.run(PendingTransactionActions.java:143)
      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
      at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8810)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:-2)
      at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:604)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1067)
      Caused by: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 542708 bytes
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(BinderProxy.java:-2)
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(BinderProxy.java:662)
        at android.app.IActivityClientController$Stub$Proxy.activityStopped(IActivityClientController.java:1334)
        at android.app.ActivityClient.activityStopped(ActivityClient.java:89)
        at android.app.servertransaction.PendingTransactionActions$StopInfo.run(PendingTransactionActions.java:143)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8810)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:-2)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:604)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1067)
    
    Thread 2:
    0   dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(VMStack.java:-2)
    1   java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:1841)
    2   java.lang.Thread.getAllStackTraces(Thread.java:1909)
    3   com.microsoft.appcenter.crashes.Crashes.saveUncaughtException(Crashes.java:1146)
    4   com.microsoft.appcenter.crashes.Crashes.saveUncaughtException(Crashes.java:1110)
    5   
    
    Thread 6987:
    0   java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:-2)
    1   java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:386)
    2   java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:524)
    3   java.lang.Daemons$ReferenceQueueDaemon.runInternal(Daemons.java:239)
    4   java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run(Daemons.java:145)
    5   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
    
    Thread 6996:
    0   jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:-2)
    1   java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:341)
    2   java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionNode.block(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:506)
    3   java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.unmanagedBlock(ForkJoinPool.java:3466)
    4   java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.managedBlock(ForkJoinPool.java:3437)
    5   java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1623)
    6   java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:435)
    7   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1071)
    8   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1131)
    9   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:644)
    10  java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
    
    Thread 6999:
    0   jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:-2)
    1   java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:341)
    2   java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionNode.block(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:506)
    3   java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.unmanagedBlock(ForkJoinPool.java:3466)
    4   java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.managedBlock(ForkJoinPool.java:3437)
    5   java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1623)
    6   java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:435)
    7   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1071)
    8   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1131)
    9   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:644)
    10  java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
    
    Thread 7000:
    0   jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:-2)
    1   java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:341)
    2   java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionNode.block(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:506)
    3   java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.unmanagedBlock(ForkJoinPool.java:3466)
    4   java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.managedBlock(ForkJoinPool.java:3437)
    5   java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1623)
    6   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1176)
    7   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:905)
    8   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1071)
    9   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1131)
    10  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:644)
    11  com.google.android.gms.common.util.concurrent.zza.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@17.6.0:2)
    12  java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
    
    Thread 7181:
    0   jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:-2)
    1   java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:341)
    2   java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack$SNode.block(SynchronousQueue.java:288)
    3   java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.unmanagedBlock(ForkJoinPool.java:3466)
    4   java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.managedBlock(ForkJoinPool.java:3437)
    5   java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:397)
    6   java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.take(SynchronousQueue.java:886)
    7   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1071)
    8   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1131)
    9   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:644)
    10  java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
    
    Thread 7208:
    0   jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:-2)
    1   java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:252)
    2   java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1672)
    3   java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.poll(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:460)
    4   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1070)
    5   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1131)
    6   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:644)
    7   com.google.android.gms.common.util.concurrent.zza.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@17.6.0:2)
    8   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
    
    Thread 7209:
    0   jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:-2)
    1   java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:252)
    2   java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1672)
    3   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.poll(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1224)
    4   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.poll(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:905)
    5   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1070)
    6   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1131)
    7   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:644)
    8   com.google.android.gms.common.util.concurrent.zza.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@17.6.0:2)
    9   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
```

Tried debugging the app but I am not able to replicate the crash anywhere.

Comment: You're experienceing a bug in your code, that's leading to framework crash. I suggest you share here your code that is sending data to server, and also to open an issue to: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues because this crash seems like an issue in Microsoft's code: "com.microsoft.appcenter.crashes.Crashes.saveUncaughtException"